# How do I create a hash of a file on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, hash, md5, sha256

I'm trying to create unique file names by renaming them using their hashed value in iOS. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could achieve this by extending NSString,
Try this in your .h:

```
@interface NSString(MD5)

- (NSString *)generateMD5Hash

@end
```

and this in your .m

```
- (NSString*)generateMD5Hash
{
  const char *string = [self UTF8String];
  unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
  CC_MD5(string, strlen(string), md5Buffer);
  NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
  for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) 
    [output appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];
  return output;
}
```

you can implement this by making a new class called NSString+MD5, and inserting the code above in the corresponding files (.h and .m)

EDIT: Do not forget to import

> < CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h >

EDIT 2:

And for NSData;

```
@interface NSData(MD5)

- (NSString *)generateMD5Hash;

@end
```

your .m:

```
- (NSString *)generateMD5Hash
{
  unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
  CC_MD5(self.bytes, (CC_LONG)self.length, md5Buffer);
  NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
  for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) 
    [output appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];

  return output;
}
```

Please note that the value returned is autorelease and might need to be retained by the receiver.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd change this to use an NSData instead, since that's what you get when reading a file. It's trivial to get a const char array from a NSData.

Comment: Thanks @August Lilleaas! I implemented this solution and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply generate unique identifiers and use it? like

```
CFUUIDRef uuidObj = CFUUIDCreate(nil);
NSString *uniqueId = (NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidObj);
CFRelease(uuidObj);
NSLog(@"%@",uniqueId);
[uniqueId autorelease];
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, decided to use the above solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Using NSData is an expensive choice. Better use NSFileHandler extension if you are dealing with big files anytime.