# What is the proper way to hash passwords in modern objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

Can anyone provide information on the proper way to hash passwords using objective c (ios 6+)? I'm looking for examples and can't find anything clear out there.

Comment: Check [MD5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632145/how-do-i-create-a-hash-of-a-file-on-ios) [SHA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454620/how-to-sha-hash-in-cocoa-ios)

Comment: Good stuff Midhun - thanks! I'm still hoping to find a nice clear tutorial, but don't think there's one out there yet. I think I can use the SHA function though.

Comment: I love the way people down-vote questions just because they're duplicates. If I had found that in my searching, do you really think I'd have asked for help??

Comment: Please check these tutorials too. [1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1),[2](http://maniacdev.com/2010/09/tutorial-how-to-calculate-md5-or-sha-hash-of-file-efficiently),[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5),[4](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/Common%20Crypto.3cc.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3cc/CommonCrypto),[5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid doing your own hashing and store them in the Keychain for security.

**UPDATE**

There are probably many ways to do this, but the way I have sent info securely over the net is to simply use the https protocol. See [this question, answer and discussion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7057/i-just-send-username-and-password-over-https-is-this-ok).

As an aside, why even do this at all? The OAuth protocol has been invented for this purpose, and is fairly easy to setup.

Comment: But don't you think storing a hashed password in the keychain would provide even better security? Defense in depth...

Comment: I know nothing about your app, but unless you are dealing with bank records, medical records or govt secrets, I would bet that the encryption Apple has on the keychain is probably good enough.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I'll be sending them to a web service.

Comment: coneybeare, can you guide me to a good tutorial for setting up oauth for this purpose? I have researched it, but still don't fully understand it yet.